# MySQL database access without hostname via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, proxy

I'm doing this for a couple of years now but I haven't faced anything like this. I'm renting a webserver which has MySQL storage. For security reasons the hosting company refused to give me a host name to connect to the MySQL server from a php script. The reason was that there is an IP filter on he server and one can only connect to it with a whitelisted ip. Is there any solution for this situation like a server sided proxy? Also I do have access to the MySQL server via phpMyadmin.
I did some research and I've found that `Navicat` has proxy support. Altough it's not free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds like you have a server with MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin all running on the same server. If that's the case then typically the hostname for MySQL will be "localhost", possibly with a port or other code added. It is quite common for web hosting companies to not allow remote MySQL access, though the good ones will have it off by default and let you turn it on either for specific IPs (best) or for "everywhere".

When you are logged into phpMyAdmin, take a look at the very top of the main window and you should see something like **Server: localhost** or **Server: www.example.com:3306** - that is your hostname for any MySQL access, provided the PHP code is running on the same server as phpMyAdmin.

If you actually need to run a program on a different server and access that MySQL database then you are probably out of luck.